# Trying to write a code in Prolog that I enter a list that contains Strings and Numbers and I want to get the maximum Number between them

Tags: list, prolog, max

That's how my list should look like `[[item(tag(""),data(""),ValidBit,N)|T]` but I only care on the last one in the list which is N and I want to get the maximum number between them all.

My best case which works is `max_l([don't care,don't care,don't care,N)],N)`.

I don't know how the rest should work.

Comment: None of your sample stuff is valid Prolog. You should read two things: (1) [How to Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ) and (2) [How to use Stack Overflow's MarkDown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  It is unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish. Showing your code is good. Along with sample data, and expected and actual results, and a good problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb and make the assumption that the data in question is a list of `item/3` terms:

```
[
  item(_,_,N1),
  item(_,_,N2),
  item(_,_,N3),
  . . .
]
```

And that our intrepid adventurer would like to find the maximum value of the third argument of each `item/3` term in the list.

Assuming that, something like this would work (not using any built-ins, because it also seems a reasonable assumption that this is schoolwork):

```
max_item_n( []                  , _   ) :- % if the list is empty
  !, fail.                                 %   there is no max value
max_item_n( [item(_,_,N)|Items] , Max ) :- % if the list is non-empty
  max_item_n_helper(Items,N,Max) .             seed the reducer with the value of the head and invoke it

max_item_n_helper( []                  , Max , Max ) .  % once the list is exhausted, we're done.
max_item_n_helper( [item(_,_,N)|Items] , T   , Max ) :- % otherwise...
  max(N,T,Max),                                         % determine the larger of N and T, and
  max_item_n_helper( Items, T1, Max )                   % recurse down on the tail
  .

max( N , T , N ) :- N > T, !.
max( N , T , T ) .
```